# The third column is not executed on my code

Tags: sql

I am calculating a percentage in t3 on the same table by doing the ratio t1/t2, unfortunately I have no result.
Can you help me fix this code?

Thanks in advance

```
select 
( --Echantillon en test
 SELECT count(*) nombre_enreg
 FROM prdiction_AVC1) as t1
( --Nombre total AVC(H/F)
select count(*)
from prdiction_AVC1
where stroke=1) as t2

Select 
       --Echantillon en test
    (( SELECT count(*) nombre_enreg
       FROM prdiction_AVC1) Echantillon
           /
         ( --Nombre total AVC(H/F)
        select count(*)
        from prdiction_AVC1
        where stroke=1) Total_avc))*100 as t3
 from t1,t2
 
 from prdiction_AVC1;
```

Comment: You can also do this with `case` statements, which would save you some time - e.g. `count(case when stroke = 1 then ID end)*100.0/count(*)`

Comment: When you say "no result" do you mean that the column is not returned at all, or that it is returning the wrong values (e.g. integer division), or that it is returning NULLs?

Comment: APH's first comment should be your solution, but replace "ID" with 1.

Answer (score 1):

APH basically answered this with his/her first comment, but this is what you can do:

```
select 
 count(*) as total, 
 count(case when stroke = 1 then 1 end) as sub_total,
 count(case when stroke = 1 then 1 end)*100.0/count(*) as sub_pct
from prdiction_AVC1
```

Output:

```
total  sub_total  sub_pct
3      1          33.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

I express myself differently.
I want to create a third column on the same table. This column should calculate the percentage ratio by doing (t2/t1)*100

If I stop at the first two requests, everything is fine, unfortunately when I add the third, I get a blocking message, so the third column is not displayed.

SELECT
--Nombre d'individus en test(H/F)
(SELECT count(*)
FROM prdiction_AVC1) as t1,

```
     --Nombre total AVC(H/F)
     (select count(*)
      from prdiction_AVC1
      where stroke=1) as t2,
      
      select t2/t1*100 as t3
       from t1,t2
```

from prdiction_AVC1;

Comment: It's not working for several reasons, such as invalid sub-queries/joins and having FROM twice in same statement.

Comment: This is not an answer, please improve the original question instead of posting clarification of the question as an answer

Answer (score 0):

i have find myself solution
Thanks all

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

--Nombre d'individus en test(H/F)
( SELECT count(*) nombre_enreg
FROM prdiction_AVC1) as Echantillon,

```
 (--Nombre total AVC(H/F)
  select count(*) total_AVC
  from prdiction_AVC1
  where stroke=1) as Nombre_avc,

 (wITH
     -- Forcer une colonne au real type de données
     -- syntaxe SELECT CAST( expression AS type )
     -- t1=echantillon, t2= nombre avc
        t1 AS
        (sELECT cast(COUNT(*) as real) nombre_enreg
        FROM prdiction_AVC1)
        ,
     --- 
        t2 AS
        (SELECT COUNT(*) total_AVC FROM prdiction_AVC1
        where stroke=1)
        SELECT round((t2.total_AVC/t1.nombre_enreg)*100,2) AS result FROM t1, t2) as pourcentage_avc
```

from prdiction_AVC1;